# Akka.net message immutabilty

Tags: c#, .net, immutability, actor, akka.net

I've been working through the [Akka.net bootcamp](https://github.com/petabridge/akka-bootcamp) and ran across something that's been puzzling me based on things I've read about messages.

In the [messaging documentation](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/sending-messages) it states that messages should be immutable.

In unit 2 of the bootcamp, the [Initialize Chart](https://github.com/petabridge/akka-bootcamp/blob/master/src/Unit-2/lesson5/Completed/Actors/ChartingActor.cs#L28) message appears to be mutable on a couple levels.

```
public class InitializeChart
{
    public InitializeChart(Dictionary<string, Series> initialSeries)
    {
        InitialSeries = initialSeries;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, Series> InitialSeries { get; private set; }
}
```

First off, the dictionary contents can be modified (add, remove, etc).  Secondly the dictionary items, [Series](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series(v=vs.110).aspx),
 are mutable.

I have 2 questions:

1) Am I in error with my interpretation of how an Akka.net message should be built?  (this example is actually correct.)

2) Should Akka.net messages be immutable all the way down?  For example, if this message was changed to:

```
public class InitializeChart
{
    public InitializeChart(Dictionary<string, Series> initialSeries)
    {
        InitialSeries = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, Series>(initialSeries);
    }

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Series> InitialSeries { get; private set; }
}
```

Would that satisfy the requirements of an Akka.net message, or should the Series elements also be immutable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that message should be using a `IReadOnlyDictionary` in order to be immutable. You are correct. The element objects themselves should also consist of read-only properties.

Comment: This is a great question, that I have been struggling with myself. My question is also... "What about the 'Series' object?". Here we don't have control over the object we're sending (it's part of MS visualisation namespace)... so to be true to immutable requirements, we would need to create an identical Series object, which had all it's attributes and methods set to 'private', and then do a laborious copy operation from the MS Series object to our new read-only version? Having to do this for many objects that are outside of our control... feels like a LOT of double work.

Comment: @ProxyTech worse case scenario, you can enable this HOCON setting https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/core/Akka/Configuration/Pigeon.conf#L91 - this will create a deep copy of each message via serialization. This setting is a bit of a performance-killer though and it's primary use is for testing. On top of that, if the mutable object you're trying to copy isn't serializable... Then it can't help :p

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. Yeah, I saw the serialisation / deep copy HOCON config option... but was put off by the 40% performance hit. I think I'm going to have to just create stripped down immutable versions of the classes... what a pain!

Comment: Alternatively, you can always just include a mutable object on your message and have consumers make a copy of it before they modify it, but that's dangerous. Strong chance if you get someone on your team who's not familiar with actors they'll torch the system by accident.

Comment: Perhaps this is something you can help me understand. If I create a message with a mutable object on it, and send the message from one actor to another... aren't ALL messages ultimately serialised before being transported to another actor (to ensure a common transportation mechanism for local/remote actors)... so wouldn't the message that they receive essentially be a new copy and in no way related to the version on the sending actor?

Comment: Never mind, I think I found the answer to my quesiton: http://getakka.net/articles/networking/serialization.html#verification